# Finding max valued of a feild based on the value in another row

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file as below (example snippet) and I want to find out the task that has taken the maximum time , the time field does not have to be immediately followed by the task field.

```
task: a
time:10
log: akjafgasgf
...
....
task:b

log: taskb
.....
time:30
....
....

task:c
time:20
....
....
log:hhhhs
```

Sample output of above input is
    task:b  time:30

I have tried

```
awk -F":" '/task/{i=$2}{if($0 ~ "time" ) arr[i]=$2}END{for(i in arr) print i,arr[i]}'  filename  | sort -nr -k2,2  | head -n1
```

and it works but I think this can be more optimized , so Please advise something better than this.

Comment: it isn't clear how the tasks are separated. 1.) the new `task: key` introduces a new `task` or 2.) theyre separated by an empty line or 3.) other?

Comment: yes the `task:key`   introduces new task

Comment: header is misleading, there is no summation involved.

Comment: corrected the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a wholesale solution, assumes tasks precede times and one to one.

```
awk -F' *: *' '$1=="task" {n=$2} 
               $1=="time" {t[n]=$2} 
               END        {for(n in t) print n,t[n]}' file | 
sort -k2nr
```

will give

```
b 30
c 20
a 10
```

note the handling of white space around the field delimiter, as in your first task.  You can of course sort in `awk` as well by using an index array, but the tool already exist for this task.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
awk -F: '
  $1=="task" { ct = $2 }
  $1=="time" { if($2 > mti){ mti = $2; mta = ct }  }
  END        { printf("task:%s time:%s\n",mta, mti) }
' yourfile
```

- `:` is used as separator (`-F:`)
- the current task is stored in `ct`, this means that we need a task **before** a time line
- when we see the `time` line the value in `$2` is compared with the max time value seen so far; `mti` and `mta` are updated if necessary
- in the `END` the max values are printed

Comment: was about to post similar answer :) `awk -F: '/^task/{t=$0} /^time/ && $2>mt{mt=$2; task=t} END{print task, mt}'`

Answer (score 0):

Perl :) (also sums multiple times for the given task)

```
perl -nlE '
    $t = $1        if /^task:\s*(.*)/;
    $s->{$t} += $1 if /^time:\s*(.*)/;
    }{
    say "$_: $s->{$_}" for sort { $s->{$b} <=> $s->{$a} } keys %$s
' tasks.txt
```

output

```
b: 30
c: 20
a: 10
```

or

```
perl -nlE '
        $t = $1        if /^task:\s*(.*)/;
        $s->{$t} += $1 if /^time:\s*(.*)/;
        }{
        say "$_: $s->{$_}" for [sort { $s->{$b} <=> $s->{$a} } keys %$s]->[0]
' tasks.txt
```

output

```
b: 30
```

would be **much** better to use an nice, full-featured perl script instead of such hackish "multiliner". But YMMV - you can always squeeze it into one unreadable line, as:

```
perl -nlE '$t=$1if/^task:\s*(.*)/;$s->{$t}+=$1if/^time:\s*(.*)/}{say"$_: $s->{$_}"for sort{$s->{$b}<=>$s->{$a}}keys%$s' task
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F: '/^task/{ta=$0} /^time/&&($2>ti||ti==""){ti=$2;b=ta OFS $0} END{print b}' file
task:b time:30
```

Explained:

```
awk -F: '                         # set delimiter
/^task/ { ta=$0 }                 # buffer task record
/^time/ && ( $2>ti || ti=="" ) {  # if time value larger than previous max
    ti=$2                         # store new max time value
    b=ta OFS $0                   # construct ouput buffer while at it
} 
END {
    print b                       # output max
}' file
```